# Upgrading Laravel 5.0 to the latest version (7.x)

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

I have been assigned with an old Laravel project (version 5.0). The first task is to upgrade the Laravel from **version 5.0** to the latest **version 7.x** (as of today).

From the Laravel docs, i found out that it's gonna take a painful long process! I know that there's a paid service called **Laravel Shift**, that will involved quite a huge money as this is huge version jump. So, Laravel Shift is not an option for me.

Can I install the latest version of Laravel, and **copy and paste all the MVC files** from the old version? has anyone done this method and succeed right away?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you follow the documentation. Check the changes for each version update and fix whatever needs fixing.

Answer (score 7):

**First**, let's **upgrade php** to at least 7.2.5 Given below commands are for 7.4

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt -y install php7.4
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-{bcmath,bz2,intl,gd,mbstring,mysql,zip,xml,curl,json}
php -v
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

For verification, check {url}/phpinfo.php

**Second**, remove **composer.lock** file & **vendor** folder `rm -R vendor`.
Run `composer install`.

**Third**, and this is where everything goes to HELL!!
*Changes in code after upgrade*

**1) The has Method**
The $request->has method will now return true even if the input value is an empty string or null. A new $request->filled method has been added that provides the previous behaviour of the has method.

e.g.

```
array:1 [
  "class_teachers" => null
]

$request->has('class_teachers')
true

$request->filled('class_teachers')
false
```

**2)** Remove html special characters from html page title.

**3) Nested Ternary Operations**
Must explicitly use parentheses to dictate the order of the operations.

```
1 ? 2 : 3 ? 4 : 5;       // deprecated
(1 ? 2 : 3) ? 4 : 5;     // ok
1 ? 2 : (3 ? 4 : 5);     // ok
```

**4) The or Operator**
The Blade "or" operator has been removed in favor of PHP's built-in ?? "null coalesce" operator

```
$user->name or "-"  -->   $user->name ?? "-"
```

**5) The Input Facade**

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,  -->  'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
```

**6) Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated**

```
$str = "test";
echo $str{0};  // deprecated
echo $str[0];  // ok
```

**7) withCount Column Formatting**
When using an alias, the withCount method will no longer automatically append _count onto the resulting column name.

**8) Logging**
All logging configuration is now housed in its own config/logging.php configuration file. You should place a copy of the default configuration file in your own application and tweak the settings based on your application's needs.

The log and log_level configuration options may be removed from the config/app.php configuration file.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
Log::info('Showing user profile for user: '.$id);
```

**9) Queue**
The **QUEUE_DRIVER** environment variable has been **renamed to QUEUE_CONNECTION**. This should not affect existing applications that you are upgrading unless you intentionally modify your config/queue.php configuration file. And change default QUEUE_CONNECTION to database

Also change .env file (VERY IMPORTANT)

**10) TTL in seconds**

```
// Laravel 5.7 - Store item for 30 minutes...
Cache::put('foo', 'bar', 30);

// Laravel 5.8 - Store item for 30 seconds...
Cache::put('foo', 'bar', 30);
```

**11) Carbon 2.0**
Laravel now supports both Carbon 1 and Carbon 2; therefore, Composer will try to upgrade to Carbon 2.0 if no other compatibility issues with any other packages are detected. Please review the [migration guide for Carbon 2.0](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2).

**12) The whereDate Method**
The query builder's whereDate method now converts DateTime instances to Y-m-d format:

```
// previous behaviour - SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `created_at` > '2018-08-01 13:00:00'
$query->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::parse('2018-08-01 13:00:00'));

// current behaviour - SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `created_at` > '2018-08-01'
$query->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::parse('2018-08-01 13:00:00'));
```

.
.
.
There can be more as well. This is something I had to do when upgrading my project. Please go through the [migration guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade)

At least, I hope, I was able to give you a head start. Good Luck!

Comment: first, install the latest Laravel version (7.x), then copy and paste my old MVC into the newly installed Laravel. and then do the code changes as you suggested above, am i right?

Comment: You can do that too.