# How to update laravel 5.4 to laravel 7 and how to update symphony process to 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

[image: when update laravel 5.4 to 7 shows following error]

when update laravel 5.4 to 7 shows following error

Comment: There are upgrade guides for every version: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

Comment: Yeah, that's a big jump... You need to follow the upgrade guides for Laravel 5.4 > 5.5, 5.5 > 5.6, etc etc until you're at the desired version. Alternatively, there are paid tools to do this for you, like Laravel Shift (https://laravelshift.com/)

Comment: Couple of weeks ago, I answered a similar question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766801/upgrading-laravel-5-0-to-the-latest-version-7-x/61767315#61767315

Comment: Tim Lewis can I follow step by step to upgrade, is their not any way to directly upgrade to 5.4 to 7?